# What's wrong with my align code?

Tags: align

I want to align some equations, but it's not aligning properly, code:

```
\begin{center}
\begin{align*}

a*b=&h_1k_1h_2k_2\\
=&h_1(h_2h_2^{-1})k_1h_2k_2\\
=&h_1h_2(h_2^{-1}k_1h_2)k_2\\
=&h_1h_2(h_2k_1h_2^{-1})^{-1}k_2

\end{align*} 
\end{center}
```

I want them lined up by the equal signs, but upon compiling that is not at all what's happening and I really wonder why. My preamble is `\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb, amsfonts, mathtools}`. Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you want to align by the equal signs, you need to put ampersands before them i.e., `&=`. Also, you don't need `center` environment because `align` centers the formula (in the default setting).

Comment: Aside/off-topic: The `mathtools` package loads the `amsmath` package automatically; thus, no need to load `amsmath` separately.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Three suggestions: (i) Don't encase the `align*` environment in a `center` environment; (ii) don't allow blank lines inside an `align*` (or other display math) environment; and (iii) write `&=` rather than `=&` if you want proper spacing around the `=` symbols.

The corrected code:

```
\begin{align*}
a*b&=h_1k_1h_2k_2\\
   &=h_1(h_2h_2^{-1})k_1h_2k_2\\
   &=h_1h_2(h_2^{-1}k_1h_2)k_2\\
   &=h_1h_2(h_2k_1h_2^{-1})^{-1}k_2
\end{align*}
```

Comment: Thanks alot! That solves all, but one problem which I discovered now, namely that the text below this align is indented. I'm trying to comment i.e. use % before and right after the align, but it's still being indented. Any suggestions? Again thanks.

Comment: @Thomas - Do you mean to say that the text below the display math environment starts with a paragraph indentation? If so, don't leave any blank lines (which generate a paragraph break) between `\end{align*}` and the start of the text.

Comment: Thanks again, that solved all of my problems this morning. You're a Latex hero!